# Which lens can be good for a Canon SX170 to make YouTube videos?

Tags: canon, camera-basics, video

I have a Canon SX170 (I believe) and I would like to know where I could get a good lens that can fit my camera. I do YouTube videos and I'm looking for a good video lens for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually have an [SX170](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/point-and-shoot/long-zoom-cameras/powershot-sx170-is), then it is a "fixed lens" camera - you cannot change the lens as you can on an SLR or mirrorless camera. It is possible to put wide-angle or telephoto adapters on the front of the existing lens, but these almost exclusively have poor optical qualities.